# changing css properties through ajax, does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, json

I'm trying to change the background color of a div, by using ajax (to retrieve the user's color from the database). Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", data: {id: id}, url: "actions/css.php", success: function(result) {
    $('.panel').animate({left: 350, width:700});
    $('.data').html(id);
       //background color
    $('.panel').css('background-color','#' + result.bgcolor);
});
```

But the color doesn't change, I know the JSON has been retrieved by checking firebug, but it looks like a client side thing.

EDIT:

```
 $('#mainTitle').html(result.title);
```

If this doesn't seem to work, I guess it might be JSON compatibility or something.

Comment: What's the value of result.bgcolor if you `console.log(result.bgcolor)`

Comment: Does it work when you hardcode a color in place of `result.bgcolor`?

Comment: yeh it deos, i put `'#ccc'` and it worked. and the value of result.bgcolor `4d4947`

Comment: maybe its the string concantanation that im trying to put!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your $.ajax call you should specify the the dataType to json

```
$.ajax({dataType: 'json'...})
```